# Why one of my tissue sample's DEGs are plotted seperately when plotted using plotcounts and ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rna-seq

I am comparing the RNA-seq data of three ages "newborn","four" and "twenty" of an animal from three different tissues "liver", "kidney" and "brain". My coldata is shown below. I successfully ran DESeq2 tool to analyse differentially expressed genes. But when I plotted differentially expressed genes having minimum padj value using "plotCounts" and "ggplot2", the genes for one of the three tissues are plotted seperately and two together. I cant figure it out where I am going wrong. If anyone can look at my script and please suggest me to plot all the samples together. Thank you in advance for your time.

```
pasCts <- "C:/Users/krishna/Desktop/project/featurecounts_9samples/countmatrix.Rmatrix.txt"
pasAnno <- "C:/Users/krishna/Desktop/project/featurecounts_9samples/featurecounts_test.csv"

cts <- as.matrix(read.csv(pasCts,sep="\t",row.names="Geneid"))
coldata <- read.csv(pasAnno, row.names=1)

coldata <- coldata[,c("condition","tissue")]
coldata$tissue <- factor(coldata$tissue)
coldata$condition <- factor(coldata$condition)

OUTPUT:
> coldata
          condition    tissue
SRR306394      "NB"   "Liver"
SRR306395    "four"   "Liver"
SRR306396  "twenty"   "Liver"
SRR306397      "NB"  "Kidney"
SRR306398    "four"  "Kidney"
SRR306399  "twenty"  "Kidney"
SRR306400      "NB"   "Brain"
SRR306401    "four"   "Brain"
SRR306402  "twenty"   "Brain"
```

##To make the rows of the coldata and columns of the matrix(cts) same order:

```
all(rownames(coldata) %in% colnames(cts))  


all(rownames(coldata) == colnames(cts))  ### to check if the order is even

cts <- cts[, rownames(coldata)] 
all(rownames(coldata) == colnames(cts))
```

OUTPUT of matrix (cts):

```
OUTPUT:
> head(cts)
                       SRR306394 SRR306395 SRR306396 SRR306397 SRR306398 SRR306399 SRR306400 SRR306401 SRR306402
ENSMUSG00000102693         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
ENSMUSG00000064842         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
ENSMUSG00000051951         1         0         0         1         0         0        62        32        22
```

To create Deseq2 matrix object for data:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = cts,
                              colData = coldata,
                              design = ~ condition)
dds
```

Prefiltering - here we are removing rows with very low read counts.

```
keep <- rowSums(counts(dds)) >= 10
dds <- dds[keep,]
```

To set factors

```
dds$tissue <- factor(dds$tissue, levels = c("liver", "kidney", "brain"))
```

Running the differential expression analysis

```
dds <- DESeq(dds)
res <- results(dds)
res
```

To get the coefficients to build the result tables:
resultsNames(dds)
OUTPUT:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tcgr.jpg) "Intercept"                      "condition_..NB.*vs*..four."     "condition_..twenty.*vs*..four."
[4] "condition_.four.*vs*..four."    "condition_.NB.*vs*..four."      "condition_.twenty.*vs*..four."

Is it possible to get only one coefficient "condition_..NB.*vs*..four._vs..twenty"? If yes, what code shall I use?

Log fold change shrinkage based upon athe coefficients achived by resultsName(dds):

```
## FOR COEF=  AND FOUR
resLFC_20vs4 <- lfcShrink(dds, coef=3, type="apeglm")
resLFC_20vs4

## FOR COEF= NB AND FOUR
resLFC_NBvs4 <- lfcShrink(dds, coef=2, type="apeglm")
resLFC_NBvs4
```

To order our results table by the smallest p value:

```
resOrdered <- res[order(res$pvalue),]
> resOrdered
> summary(resOrdered)  ### to summarize some basic tallies using the "summary" function
```

#### to know the number of adjusted p-values less than 0.1

```
sum(res$padj < 0.1, na.rm=TRUE)OUTPUT:2472

res05 <- results(dds, alpha=0.05) ###by default alpha = 0.1 but if adjpvalue is other than 0.1 then specify
res05
summary(res05)
sum(res05$padj < 0.05, na.rm=TRUE) ### to know the number of adj p value less than 0.05
```

After running the above codes, I tried to plot the genes with min padj values using ggplot2:

```
d <- plotCounts(dds, gene=which.min(res$padj), intgroup = "condition", returnData = TRUE)  ##plotting reads with minimun padj value

> dput(d)
structure(list(count = c(23099.7389197999, 19548.8369195126, 
17799.941667842, 20473.6092655006, 18165.0693569093, 13919.6719941735, 
1008.89639856882, 581.070434144846, 576.594165656907), condition = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c(" \"four\"", " \"NB\"", 
" \"twenty\"", "\"four\"", "\"NB\"", "\"twenty\""), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("SRR306394", 
"SRR306395", "SRR306396", "SRR306397", "SRR306398", "SRR306399", 
"SRR306400", "SRR306401", "SRR306402"))

library("ggplot2")
    
ggplot(d, aes(x=condition, y=count))+
      geom_point(position=position_jitter(w=0.1,h=0))+
      scale_y_log10(breaks=c(25,100,400))
```

But the graph displays the genes of the two tissue samples plotted together while the third tissue is plotted seperately. The graph can be seen here:
[customized plotting using ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tcgr.jpg)

Can anyone suggesst me the correct code to get graphs showing all the genes of all tissues plotted together?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you post the output of `dput(d)` so we might have a better idea what is going on with the plotting code?

Comment: A few notes: 1) Without providing a contrast or a name to res, the last one is used if there are multiple contrasts, not all of them (see ?results for how to define other contrasts than the one you used). 2) You provide a lot of unused code in this example (shrinkage, ordering, filtering) that is irrelevant when plotting counts. 3) Your factor levels are shown in quotes in your plot, which is weird - a dput output of d would be really useful.

Comment: thanks @teunbrand. I have posted the output of dput(d). If I am not wrong, this is what you have asked me to show the output for. And I apologize if I am giving ypu wrong info. I am new to this subject so please guide me if I am doing anything wrong or giving you wrong details.

Comment: thanks @user127287748.1) I did provide contrast at first but it gave me padj value=1 for all the genes so I ran without adding contrast. 2) I used codes for shrinkage because I am going to use the reads to plot shrunken log fold change at later stage. 3)Yes, I have used quotes, but it didnt make any difference if they are removed. I got same output without quotations.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem and have a solution to solve it but I wouldn't know how to prevent it.

The problem was that the first three factor levels have an extra space in front of the quotes and the last three factor levels don't.

Compare `" \"four\""` with `"\"four\""` in the dput output (the `\"` pattern is just that these quotes need to be printed and are not string indicators).

So to solve this, you'd only need to replace the spaces with empty characters:

```
d$condition <- factor(gsub(" ", "", as.character(d$condition)))

ggplot(d, aes(x=condition, y=count))+
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(w=0.1,h=0))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(25,100,400))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @teunbrand, I tried your code: d$condition <- factor(gsub(" ", "", as.character(d$condition))) and it worked and later I've also realised the presence of leading spaces in my metadata. My code worked after removing those spaces. Thanks a lot. Just one more question if you can suggest me how to label the tissues on the graph I mean how one can say which tissue is which on the graph?

Comment: You'd need to have the tissuetype as a column in `d` and then colour the points based on the tissue by replacing the mappings argument with `aes(x = condition y = count, colour = tissuetype)`.